# Catalan and path pairs in polynomials

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, polynomials, enumerative-combinatorics

Define $\mathbf{K}_n$ to be the set of all $(2n+1)$-tuple sequences $\mathbf{a}=(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{2n})\in\{-1,1\}^{n+1}$ satisfying: (a) there are $n$ occurrences of $-1$ and $n+1$ of $+1$; (b) all its partial sums are positive. Denote the cardinality of $\mathbf{K}_n$ by $\mathcal{K}_n$ which equals the Catalan number $\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$. Introduce
$$f_n(q)=\sum_{\mathbf{a}\in\mathbf{K}_n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}q^{\sum_{i=0}^ka_i}.$$
**Example.** $\mathbf{K}_2=\{(1, 1, -1, 1, -1), (1, 1, 1, -1, -1)\}$ and $f_2(q)=5q+4q^2+q^3$.

**Example.** $f_3(q)=14q+14q^2+6q^3+q^4$ while
\begin{align}\mathbf{K}_3
&=\{(1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1), (1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1), (1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1), \\
& \qquad \qquad \qquad (1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1), (1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1)\}.
\end{align}

> **QUESTION.** Is this true?
> $$f_n(q)=q\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{j+1}{n+1}\binom{2n+2}{n-j}q^j.$$

**Remark 1.** The numbers $\frac{k}{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}$ are one among a plethora of Catalan triangles and they are related to [path pairs of length $n$](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X01001212?via%3Dihub) (see page 252 and up).

**Remark 2.** Evidently $f_n(1)=(2n+1)\mathcal{K}_n$ and $f_n(-1)=-\mathcal{K}_n, f'(0)=\mathcal{K}_{n+1}, f'(1)=2^{2n}$.

Comment: What about computing $\sum_{\mathbf{a}\in\mathbf{K}_n}q^{\sum_{i=0}^ka_i}$ for a fixed $k$? If this has a nice answer (which I suspect it has), then all you need to do afterwards is summing over all $k$ and simplifying (probably using Chu--Vandermonde).

Comment: That seems an interesting proposition. Denote your polynomials by $f_{n,k}(q)$ then for $n=5$, I have computed: $f_{5,11}=f_{5,1}=42q, f_{5,10}=f_{5,2}=42q^2, f_{5,9}=f_{5,3}=14q(1+2q^2), f_{5,8}=f_{5,4}=14q^2(1+2q^2), f_{5,7}=f_{5,5}=q(10+27q^2+5q^4), f_{5,6}=q^2(25+10q^2+q^4)$. These do not appear encouraging.

Comment: If you instead take $\mathbf{B}_n$ as $(2n)$-tuples which sum to 0 and have no non-negative prefix sums, this is equivalent to removing the first $1$ from elements of $\mathbf{K}_n$, so $$f_n(q)=\sum_{\mathbf{b}\in\mathbf{B}_n}q + q \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}q^{\sum_{i=0}^kb_i}$$ but the elements can be composed as in the Catalan recurrence and the resulting convolution might be tractable for a proof by induction.

Answer (score 4):

To each $\mathbf a\in\mathbf K_n$, put into correspondence the Dyck path determined by $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{2n})$ (to clarify: we assume that the Dyck paths lie under the diagonal $x=y$). Then the coefficient of $q^{j+1}$ is just the total number of points on all such paths lying on the line $\ell$ given by $y=x-j$.

To each such path $P$ and a point $(i+j,i)$ on it, put into correspondence a path $Q$ from $(0,0)$ to $(n+j+1,n-k)$ (also under the diagonal) as follows.

Let $P=P_1P_2$, where $P_1$ is a path from $(0,0)$ to $(i+j,i)$, and $P_2$ is the remainder. Reflect $P_2$ in the line $x+y=2n$ to get a path $P_2'$ under the diagonal from $(n,n)$ to $(2n-i,2n-i-j)$. Now augment $P_1$ with a single horizontal step and then with $P_2'$ shifted by an appropriate vector $(i+j+1-n,i-n)$ --- this provides a path $Q$.

The obtained path $Q$ lies under the diagonal, and does not cross the line $\ell$ after the point $(i+j,i)$. So the inverse transform is also well-defined: for each $Q$, take its last point $(i+j,i)$ on $\ell$ and then perform the backward shift and reflection with the piece of $Q$ after the point $(i+j+1,i)$.

So the required total number of points on $\ell$ equals the number of paths under the diagonal from $(0,0)$ to $(n+j+1,n-j)$, which is indeed computed as
$$
  {2n+1\choose n-j}-{2n+1\choose n-j-1}=\frac{j+1}{n+1}{2n+2\choose n-j}.
$$

**Remark.** Algebraically, the transform looks as follows. To each $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{2n})$ with $a_1+\dots+a_{2i+j}=j$, we put into correspondence the sequence $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{2i+j},1,-a_{2n},-a_{2n-1},\dots,-a_{2i+j+1})$.